# Matlab: sorting in rows

Tags: matlab, sorting

Why does this

```
t = magic(4);
k = 1:4;
tt(k,:) = sort(t(k,:)) %
```

sort values inside each column (swapping rows and cols does nothing), 
but this

```
t = magic(4);
for k = 1:4
  tt(k,:) = sort(t(k,:))
end
```

sorts values inside row, as expected?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the following

```
t = magic(4);
k = 1:4;
tt(k,:) = sort(t(k,:)) %
```

`t(k,:)` is a 4x4 *matrix*. Hence, `sort` will apply its default 1-dim sorting, i.e., w.r.t. rows. Note that you can tell `sort` to sort along the 2nd dimension. i.e., w.r.t. columns, by

```
tt(k,:) = sort(t(k,:),2)
```

---

In your other case, `k` is an integer and `t(k,:)` is a 1x4 *row vector*; hence, sorting will be performed w.r.t. columns.

```
t = magic(4);
for k = 1:4
  tt(k,:) = sort(t(k,:))
end
```

---

Finally, take note of @Luis Mendo:s clarification in the comments below, which I include here in case the comment were to be removed:

> Just a clarification: by default `sort` (like most Matlab functions),
>   doesn't work along the first dim, but along the first *non-singleton
>   dim*. The distinction is important if the input matrix can be a row
>   vector.

Comment: thank you, so easiest way to sort is just tt = sort(t,2);

Comment: Just a clarification: by default `sort` (like most Matlab functions), doesn't work along the first dim, but along the _first non-singleton_ dim. The distinction is important if the input matrix can be a row vector

Comment: That is a valuable explicit addition, thank you @LuisMendo.

Answer (score 5):

"sorts values inside row, **as expected**?" This is a wrong assumption. MATLAB uses column-major ordering. You should expect MATLAB functions to operate on columns by default. Try out functions such as `sum`, `max`, `min` etc on a 2D matrix and you will see it always works down the columns by default. Most of these function have a parameter to specify which dimension you should work along e.g.

```
sum(M,2)
```

will sum along the rows where `sum(M)` (or `sum(M,1)` for that matter) sums down the columns.

[dfri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35718772/1011724) shows you that your first case is just calling the whole 2D matrix `t` whereas your second case calls `t` row by row. When any of the above mentioned functions operates on a 1Dvector, row or column, it will operate on the entire vector ignoring dimensions.